# Content not found Facebook

Tags: facebook

I have created my app page on facebook. I have added the required setting like Google Play Package Name, Class name and key hashes but still when try to access that app page it is showing below given error instead of taking us to play store. I have search a lot in web but did not get the relevant post. But I assume this issue can be fixed by facebook settings. I would really appreciate any suggestion.

[image]

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: I guess it is not related to code. There is might be a setting in facebook developer page which I missing

Comment: Have you tried posting at http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ ? They should hopefully be able to help.

Comment: @Carlos I have the same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten the same error, and as far as I understand, the field "Mobile Site URL" no longer works, **as of July 2017**. (Apparently there was some abuse of this system.)

In order to redirect to your website, an offical Facebook support encouraged to redirect to the mobile website from within the game itself.

Be advised that according to the Platform Policy, redirecting away from Facebook **must** be done through a user interaction such as a button click. It should not be done automatically.

A simple solution may be something like this:

```
if (window.innerWidth < 992 && window !== window.top) {
    if (confirm("To get the full mobile experience, we recommend playing the game directly on our website. Would you like to play there?")) {
        window.top.location.href = 'https://www.example.com';
    }
}
```

Source: 
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1051463851558493/?disable_redirect=0